# Processes and .desktop launchers (Identification)

Tags: unity, launcher, python, icons, kupfer

I have a python application which behaves in two different ways. When started without arguments, it runs in CONFIGMODE and shows a Configuration GUI (pygtk). When started with an argument it runs in APPMODE.

Then I have two Bash-Scripts (`configmode` and `appmode`) to start. One starts my app with arguments, the other without. For each script I have created a .desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications` with different icons.

But even when I start `appmode.desktop` the Unity launcher shows the icon from `configmode.desktop`.

I also use `Kupfer` to launch applications. And when `configmode` is already running Kupfer also thinks that `appmode` is already running.

Therefore I wonder how Unity and Kupfer identify which `.desktop` file to use?

My goal is to see the icon from the `.desktop` file which I used for startup in the Unity launcher. How can I achive this?

Answer (score 2):

Unity uses the [BAMF Application Matching Framework](https://launchpad.net/bamf). I don't know about Kupfer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might not be in the desktop files themselves, but in any of the following:

- `.ui` file: If you're using a user interface file, you might have set the `icon_name` property for the main window. In such a case, I'd say that the icon in the `.desktop` file is not used.
- `pygtk` code: Similarly to the `.ui` file case, you might have set the icon for the main window using `gtk.Window.set_icon_name`, `gtk.Window.set_default_icon_name` or similar.

My advice is to programmatically set the icon for the main window when the application is started using `gtk.Window.set_icon_name` or `gtk.Window.set_default_icon_name` depending on the arguments passed to the application.